# Eclipse - Drools - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

I am trying to run a Drools app, my ecplise got corrupted, I reinstalled, reloaded drools, jbpm, maven and I can not figure out why I get this error in every drools app I run. Even working demos from github

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.asm.InvokerGenerator.createStubGenerator(InvokerGenerator.java:34)
```

Sample Code: (Confirmed worked before I had to reinstall)

```java
package com.jenn.DroolsDemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.drools.compiler.compiler.DroolsParserException;
import org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder;
import org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.*;
import org.drools.core.RuleBase;
import org.drools.core.RuleBaseFactory;
import org.drools.core.WorkingMemory;

/**
 * 
 * @author Binod Suman
 * Binod Suman Academy YouTube
 *
 */

public class DemoTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DroolsParserException, IOException {
        DemoTest client = new DemoTest();
        client.execteRule();
    }

    public void execteRule() throws DroolsParserException, IOException{
           PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();
           String ruleFile = "/offers.drl";
           InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(ruleFile);
           
           Reader ruleReader = new InputStreamReader(resourceAsStream);
           builder.addPackageFromDrl(ruleReader);
           org.drools.core.rule.Package rulePackage = builder.getPackage();
           RuleBase ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();
           ruleBase.addPackage(rulePackage);
           
           WorkingMemory workingMemory = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();
           
           PaymentOffer paymentOffer = new PaymentOffer();
           paymentOffer.setChannel("paytm");
           workingMemory.insert(paymentOffer);
           workingMemory.fireAllRules();
           
           System.out.println("The cashback for this payment channel "+paymentOffer.getChannel()+" is "+paymentOffer.getDiscount());
           
       } 
}
```

Comment: That looks like some really old drools. A.) what version of Drools are you using? 6.x? 5.x? B.) does it still fail if you run it from the commandline?

Comment: I was looking into some version and the intern helping me out with this work is using 6.0.* and I am not sure why. I did a fresh install and now just random compilation errors sorting through the old version. 

thanks for your help

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and the post above from Roddy it is confirmed my development partner is using very old drools core.  I am working to get that upgraded in the code.